# How to retrieve the datatype SIZE from the datatable

Tags: vb.net

How to retrieve the column datatype size form the data table?

```
Dim tblProducts as DataTable
.
.
.

For i As Integer = 0 To tblProducts.Rows.Count
    Dim d = tblProducts.Columns(i).DataType ' here How to retrieve the datatype size ?? :(
Next
```

Comment: you want the maximum possible size of that type in .NET? Or the max possible size in the underlying column as defined in your database (assuming this is where that came from), or the actual size of the field, or what? It's not clear what you actually mean.

Comment: i want the Data type actual size nvarchar(20 or 50 )... :(

Comment: For that you have to write a separate SQL query. The DataTable doesn't store that information, it's an abstraction of the data and will just define it as a .NET `string` variable, whose size limits are entirely different. Google how to write a SQL query (for whatever your DBMS is) which would get information about the table definition. There will almost certainly be answers. For SQL-Server in particular I know for a fact that SO has many questions on that topic.

Comment: `DataColumn.MaxLength` seems to be what you are looking for